# How to filter a Boolean field in a json join

Tags: c#, json, filter, boolean

My apologies for being back so soon. I've tried many ways, but I can't compile the code because everything I've tried tells me I can't do that with a boolean field. Every example I've searched gives examples for ? x == 1. But I'm trying to filter for a field that has a boolean value ? x == true.

I've tried filtering in the foreach loop, changing to a for loop, adding a condition to the where also to the join and a RemoveAll. I can't find/think of any other ways to try. Inexperience is killing me.

I need to filter catObj.["IncludeCategory"] == true.

Any help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class TestClass
{
  public static void Test()
  {
    // Load categories.json
    JObject catObj = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(File.OpenText("D:/Code/Tests/categories.json")));
    // Load techtypes.json
    JObject ttObj = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(File.OpenText("D:/Code/Tests/techtypes.json")));

    foreach (var categoriesJson in catObj)
        //foreach (var categoriesJson in GetCategoriesJson())
        foreach (var itemsJson in ttObj)
      {
        // Filter variables
        var gameVersions = new HashSet<string> { "A", "2" };
        var categoryIDs = new HashSet<string> { "outcrop" };

        // Left outer join on ttObj.  Select all Items[*] array items
        var query = from i in ttObj.SelectTokens("TechType[*]").OfType<JObject>()
                      // Filter on the game version and category ID
                    let categoryId = (string)i["CategoryID"]
                    let gameVersion = (string)i["GameVersion"]
                    where
                    categoryIDs.Count() > 0 ? 
                      categoryIDs.Contains(categoryId) && gameVersions.Contains(gameVersion) && gameVersions.Contains(gameVersion)  : gameVersions.Contains(gameVersion) && gameVersions.Contains(gameVersion)

                    // Join with "Categories[*]" on category ID
                    join c in catObj.SelectTokens("Categories[*]") on categoryId equals (string)c["CategoryID"] into joined
                    // DefaultIfEmpty makes this a left join
                    from cat in joined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      // Select all records of i and add the CategoryDescription from cat.
                    select new JObject(i.Properties()) { new JProperty("CategoryDescription", cat?["CategoryDescription"]) };

        var results = query.ToList(); // Materialize the query into a list of results.

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Formatting.Indented));

        Console.WriteLine();
      }
  }

  public class TechType
  {
    public string CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string TechName { get; set; }
    public string SpawnID { get; set; }
    public int TechID { get; set; }
    public string GameVersion { get; set; }
  }

  public class TechTypeRoot
  {
    public List<TechType> TechType { get; set; }
  }

  public class Categories
  {
    public string CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IncludeCategory { get; set; }
    public string GameVersion { get; set; }
  }

  public class CategoriesRoot
  {
    public List<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
  }
}

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    try
    {
      TestClass.Test();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Failed with unhandled exception: ");
      Console.WriteLine(ex);
      throw;
    }
  }
}
```

The catObj json

```
{
  "Categories": [
    {
      "CategoryID": "baseupgrades",
      "CategoryDescription": "Base Upgrades",
      "IncludeCategory": true,
      "GameVersion": "A"
    },
    {
      "CategoryID": "batteries",
      "CategoryDescription": "Batteries",
      "IncludeCategory": true,
      "GameVersion": "A"
    },
    {
      "CategoryID": "blueprint",
      "CategoryDescription": "Blueprint",
      "IncludeCategory": false,
      "GameVersion": "A"
    },
```

The ttObj json

```
{
  "TechType": [
    {
      "CategoryID": "crystalline",
      "TechName": "Quartz",
      "SpawnID": "quartz",
      "TechID": 1,
      "GameVersion": "A"
    },
    {
      "CategoryID": "metals",
      "TechName": "Metal Salvage",
      "SpawnID": "scrapmetal",
      "TechID": 2,
      "GameVersion": "A"
    },
    {
      "CategoryID": "outcrop",
      "TechName": "Limestone Outcrop",
      "SpawnID": "limestonechunk",
      "TechID": 4,
      "GameVersion": "A"
    },
```

Comment: Use the [explicit cast to Boolean](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit.htm): `(bool)catObj.["IncludeCategory"] == true`  Or if it might be missing, cast to a nullable: `(bool?)catObj.["IncludeCategory"] == true`

Comment: Is that all you need to answer your question?  You don't show any JSON in your question so it's not clear where you need to add the Boolean filter, so if you need something more specific, please share a [mcve].

Comment: @dbc I've edited the post to include examples of the json files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I had to change the join to a right join as stated in my first post. Now I can access all the fields in the where clause.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        // Load categories.json
        JObject catObj = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(File.OpenText("D:/Code/Tests/categories.json")));
        // Load techtypes.json
        JObject ttObj = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(File.OpenText("D:/Code/Tests/techtypes.json")));

        foreach (var categoriesJson in catObj)
        {
            // Filter variables
            var gameVersions = new HashSet<string> { "A", "1" };
            var categoryIDs = new HashSet<string> { "metals", "tablets" };
            var usedInMod = new HashSet<bool> { true };

            // Right outer join on catObj.  Select all Items[*] array items
            var query = from c in catObj.SelectTokens("Categories[*]").OfType<JObject>()
                                    let categoryId = (string)c["CategoryID"]

                                    // Join catObj with ttObj on CategoryID
                                    join t in ttObj.SelectTokens("TechType[*]") on categoryId equals (string)t["CategoryID"]
                                    let gameVersionC = (string)c["GameVersion"]
                                    let gameVersionT = (string)t["GameVersion"]
                                    // Process the filters
                                    where categoryIDs.Count() > 0 ?
                                    usedInMod.Contains((bool)c["UsedInMod"]) && gameVersions.Contains(gameVersionC) && gameVersions.Contains(gameVersionT) && categoryIDs.Contains(categoryId) :
                                    usedInMod.Contains((bool)c["UsedInMod"]) && gameVersions.Contains(gameVersionC) && gameVersions.Contains(gameVersionT)

                                    select new
                                    {
                                        CategoryDescription = c["CategoryDescription"],
                                        CategoryID = c["CategoryID"],
                                        TechName = t["TechName"],
                                        SpawnID = t["SpawnID"],
                                        TechID = t["TechID"],
                                        GameVersion = t["GameVersion"]
                                    };

            var results = query.ToList(); // Materialize the query into a list of results.

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results, Formatting.Indented));

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            TestClass.Test();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed with unhandled exception: ");
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```